# Python 3: String to datetime object

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have the following string I want to convert into a datetime object in Python 3:

```
"05/Feb/2016"
```

Iv'e used the following approach before:

```
datetime.date(datetime.strptime("05/02/2016", '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Now the format has changed, and I need to know what to change `'%d/%m/%Y'` into (if possible). Thanks!

Comment: Skim through your use cases and create a format accordingly, i guess it is the only way to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://strftime.org/ for reference on Python's strftime directives

In your case, this should do:

```
datetime.date(datetime.strptime("05/Feb/2016", '%d/%b/%Y'))
```

Notice `%b` is used to denote month in the 3 letter style (eg Feb)

Comment: Perfect, works! I'll accept your answer in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

To decode "Feb" if that is the correct local abbreviated name for the month, use `%b` in place of `%d`. See the `datetime` documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Alternatively investigate `dateparser` https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, or even roll your own decoder.